# USB How do you create a bootable custom USB application?

Tags: c#, c++, usb

Many LCD televisions nowadays have USB ports so you can plug in your camera and it becomes a camera gallery on the TV.

I want to write a gallery program which, when plugged in to the TV, will start to cycle through the images on the USB device.  How would I do this?  Is it possible to write some sort of OS/application which can run on the USB device alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would depend entirely on the television's firmware whether it would even be supported.  If it were, the specification of how to do it would need to be observed.

Answer (score 9):

The gallery application is built into the TV, it is not on the USB. I doubt the TV is easily modable nor is there a published API.